# Center radiobuttons in Kivy issue

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to center the radiobuttons (checkbox with group and label for the text) in kv file. I have added them to `ScrollView`, but it has a lot of space between those widgets.

**Code:**

```
        ScrollView:
            size_hint: (1, 1)

            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                padding: 0
                spacing: 0, 0
                size_hint: (1, None)
                height: self.minimum_height

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    size_hint_x: 0.60
                    spacing: 0
                    padding: 0
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                    size_hint_y: None

                    CheckBox:
                        group: "notIdentReason"
                    Label:
                        text: "Sample rejected"
                        font_size: 24
                        color: 0, 0, 0, 1

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    size_hint_x: 0.60
                    spacing: 0
                    padding: 0
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                    size_hint_y: None

                    CheckBox:
                        group: "notIdentReason"
                    Label:
                        text: "Unsubtyping"
                        font_size: 24
                        color: 0, 0, 0, 1

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    size_hint_x: 0.60
                    spacing: 0
                    padding: 0
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                    size_hint_y: None

                    CheckBox:
                        group: "notIdentReason"
                    Label:
                        text: "Other"
                        font_size: 24
                        color: 0, 0, 0, 1
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

How to remove the space between the radiobutton and label? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key is to use `minimum_size` for your `GridLayout` and `BoxLayouts`, and to set the sizes of its children, the `CheckBox` and the `Label`. Something like this:

```
ScrollView:
    size_hint: (None, 1)
    width: grid.width
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}

    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        cols: 1
        padding: 0
        spacing: 0, 0
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.minimum_size
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.minimum_size
            spacing: 0
            padding: 0

            CheckBox:
                group: "notIdentReason"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: lab.height, lab.height
            Label:
                id: lab
                text: "Sample rejected"
                font_size: 24
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.minimum_size
            spacing: 0
            padding: 0

            CheckBox:
                group: "notIdentReason"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: lab.height, lab.height
            Label:
                text: "Unsubtyping"
                font_size: 24
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.minimum_size
            spacing: 0
            padding: 0

            CheckBox:
                group: "notIdentReason"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: lab.height, lab.height
            Label:
                text: "Other"
                font_size: 24
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
```

Comment: Great! Thank you.